# SLD : setting Multiple Values in one Literal Tag

Tags: geoserver, sld

Is it possible to use multiple values in one `Literal` tag?

This is what I have:

```
    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
      <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
```

I want to symbolize multiple attributes in one block rather than repeat the above line dozens of times.  And unfortunately my table values are not very friendly so I can't use a greater than call.  I was hoping for something similar to below (Literal Tag)

```
    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
      <ogc:Literal>0;10;60;40</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
```

And the next Rule would be something like this:

```
    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
      <ogc:Literal>1;11;62;42</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would go with something like:

```
<ogc:Function name="in">
    <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
    <ogc:Literal>11</ogc:Literal>
    <ogc:Literal>62</ogc:Literal>
    <ogc:Literal>42</ogc:Literal>
</ogc:Function>
```

Alternatively generate a new column in the database with the new classes precomputed in it.

Comment: can this be used to get the geojson data from WMS by POST request ?

Comment: Should the whole PropertyIsEqualTo block be replaced by this?

Answer (score -3):

You can use other operators like:

```
<PropertyIsEqualTo>
<PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
<PropertyIsLessThan>
<PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
<PropertyIsGreaterThan>
<PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
```

Check here the [geoserver doc](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/filters.html).

For array, check the "in" [comparison function](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#comparison-functions).

Comment: Those won't work because of the table.