# how to call a function within an SLD

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have the below SLD and I I need to filter based on multiple (several dozen) that do not meet the criteria:

```
<PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
<PropertyIsLessThan>
<PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
<PropertyIsGreaterThan>
<PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
```

And I can not edit the DB table so I am left with `<ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>`.  Is there a way to filter with multiple `Literal statments` within the function? if I add a second `Literal` call i get the error:

```
line 20: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ogc:Literal'. No child element is expected at this point.
```

I can not duplicate the code because it creates a new legend category for each filter.  Using [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192350/sld-setting-multiple-values-in-one-literal-tag) I have been researching functions but I still have been unable to filter with multiple values.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>test</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>Other</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Title>Other</Title>
          <ogc:Filter>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:Function name="in">
              <ogc:PropertyName>type</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:Function>
              <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              </ogc:Filter>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>arrow</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <CssParameter name="fill">#0033cc</CssParameter>
                </Fill>
              </Mark>
              <Size>12</Size>
              <Rotation>
                <ogc:PropertyName>dir</ogc:PropertyName>
              </Rotation>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
     </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compare the result of the function to true, so your example would look like:

```
  <ogc:Filter>
     <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       <ogc:Function name="in">
          <ogc:PropertyName>type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Literal>23</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Literal>42</ogc:Literal>
       </ogc:Function>
       <ogc:Literal>true</ogc:Literal>
     </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
   </ogc:Filter>
```